# Novel about an AI (robot) becoming more human than the owner

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

An engineer has been shot, he was working on creating AI. His neural connections were broken and some kind of robot helped him to repair neural networks. The robot has micromanipulators each of which could split into two which were twice smaller (like a recursive tree structure), then he started to work on AI, created brain-computer interface through these manipulators. Then, using this brain-computer interface with help of the robot he created AI. And they started to share mind with this AI through the brain-computer interface.

Meanwhile, the engineer was becoming more and more senseless while the robot (AI) instead started to be more and more human.

I read it about 5 - 10 years ago. It was quite short I was able to print it. And in my opinion, at that time, it was new.

PS: Some american scientist with a Japanese last name was editor of this book.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guide. I checked it, do you have something specific in mind which I should fix? Because It looks like I tried my best to remember all key details.

Comment: If you know what the acronym stand for, then you should edit that if for any who don't know.

Comment: I have added in the PPS acronym definition, but you are right. Fixed.

Comment: "The robot has micromanipulators each of which could split into two which were twice smaller (like a recursive tree structure)" -- this is *not* the book being searched for, but I believe I first encountered this idea in a Charles Stross novel, probably Singularity Sky.  Very cool idea. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the book you're thinking of is [The Turing Option](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1807642.The_Turing_Option) from 1992. [The LA Times review of the book](http://articles.latimes.com/1992-09-01/news/vw-6690_1_turing-option) has a plot summary.

The robot's micromanipulators you mention are described [around page 124](https://books.google.com/books?id=Re0-8V8fprUC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=octree&f=false).